# Does Container Node on Title Bar in Application Layout work

Tags: xpages, xpages-extlib

I'm using the Application Layout control, and on the Title Bar, I'm adding a Container Node with 2 (or more) children Basic Nodes, although I have tried several other children types for experimentation purposes.  The label for the container node is displayed on the page, but none of the functionality of a container node is present.  The same container node works as expected in the banner, place bar, and footer, but not in the Title Bar.

Is this a bug or is there another setup step I need to take?
Are there any workarounds to get this to work in the Title Bar?

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core" xmlns:xe="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/coreex">
    <xe:applicationLayout id="applicationLayout1">
        <xe:this.configuration>
            <xe:oneuiApplication
                legal="false"
                footer="false"
                banner="false"
                placeBar="false">
                <xe:this.footerLinks></xe:this.footerLinks>
                <xe:this.titleBarTabs>
                    <xe:basicContainerNode label="Container 1">
                        <xe:this.children>
                            <xe:basicLeafNode
                                label="Link 1"
                                href="url1">
                            </xe:basicLeafNode>
                            <xe:basicLeafNode
                                label="Link 2"
                                href="url2">
                            </xe:basicLeafNode>
                        </xe:this.children>
                    </xe:basicContainerNode>
                </xe:this.titleBarTabs>
                <xe:this.placeBarActions></xe:this.placeBarActions>
                <xe:this.bannerApplicationLinks></xe:this.bannerApplicationLinks>
            </xe:oneuiApplication>
        </xe:this.configuration>
    </xe:applicationLayout>
</xp:view>
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a bug one why or another. 
Usually only tabs are placed here so it is either that container nodes aren't supported here and they should be removed as an option to developers to add them to the TitleBar, or that the container node just doesn't work in the Title Bar. 
I've logged 'PHAN9FDDFX' to track this issue regardless of the outcome.

Comment: Thanks Paul; as you said, it may be a bug one way or the other. But I also suspect I'm trying to use the Title Bar in a non-standard way.

Answer (score 0):

Never tried it the way described by you; I always put the tree nodes directly into the titleBarTabs, as it's done in the Extlib demo database:

```
<xe:this.titleBarTabs>
    <xe:pageTreeNode page="Core_Home" selection="/Core/.*" label="Core">
    </xe:pageTreeNode>
    <xe:pageTreeNode page="Domino_Home" selection="/Domino/.*" label="Domino">
    </xe:pageTreeNode>
    <xe:pageTreeNode page="DWA_Home" selection="/DWA/.*" label="iNotes">
    </xe:pageTreeNode>
    <xe:pageTreeNode loaded="false" page="iWidget_Home" selection="/iWidget/.*" label="iWidget">
    </xe:pageTreeNode>
    <xe:pageTreeNode page="Mobile_Home" selection="/Mobile/.*" label="Mobile">
    </xe:pageTreeNode>
    <xe:pageTreeNode page="OneUI_Home" selection="/OneUI/.*" label="OneUI">
    </xe:pageTreeNode>
    <xe:pageTreeNode page="REST_Home" selection="/REST/.*" label="REST">
    </xe:pageTreeNode>
</xe:this.titleBarTabs>
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Yes, pageTreeNodes work for me, as do basicLeafNodes. I'm probably trying to use the Title Bar and titleBarTabs in a way they are not designed for in the Application Layout control.  Thanks.